# Is there a LEGO Tyre Shop set?

Tags: sets

Is there a LEGO set of a tyre shop (garage)? In other words, a set with play features where tyres could be disassembled by a tyre-changing machine, with a lift for cars or bikes, and other tools for this kind of work?

If it does, please could you give me the set number?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you are asking for a set that has play features resembling an auto mechanic's shop, then you have a few options:

---

The closest is probably **[1966 Car Repair Shop](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/1966-1)**.

[image: 1966 Car Repair Shop]

1966 Car Repair Shop is a 1985 set.  It does not feature a lift, but it does have a jack, and includes a wrench (and other play features) that simulate a mechanic's shop.

---

Another good choice that's still in production is **[4207 City Garage](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/City-Garage-4207)**

[image: 4207 City Garage]

City Garage has an elevator lift (no mechanic access underneath it), and it has a mechanics shop, including spare tires and tools to work on the cars.  However, it's not as "good" of a shop as 1996.

---

Lastly, if you're ok with Duplo, the closest set is **[3619 Traffic City](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/3619-1)**.

[image: 3619 Traffic City]

3619 Traffic City features a real working lift and mechanics shop.  However, it also features other play features like 4207 City Garage.

Answer (score 6):

There is a new one. It's set number 60097.

[image: lego 60097 garage]